# Can't edit texture of cube unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm quite new to unity and was wondering why I could not edit the texture of this cube.
Thank you!

For some reason it is 'greyed out':
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND7ep.png)

Thank you!

Comment: You you add a bit more details?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a cube (or any built-in gameobject) in unity, it is assigned a default material. This is not editable. Create a new material and assign it to your cube. You can edit it anyway you want.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the model or material section, choose the material and duplicate it. Now you can use that material on your object.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBxYl.png)